# Como fazer truncamento de texto sem cortar palavras .NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, string

Estou tentando de várias formas a dias mas não tenho conseguido fazer este *script* pegar o valor do `<h3>` e retornar o texto para ele truncado.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function truncar() {

        var texto = document.getElementById("texto_noticia");
        var limite = 350;

        if (texto.length > limite) {
            limite--;
            last = texto.substr(limite - 1, 1);
            while (last != ' ' && limite > 0) {
                limite--;
                last = texto.substr(limite - 1, 1);
            }
            last = texto.substr(limite - 2, 1);
            if (last == ',' || last == ';' || last == ':') {
                texto = texto.substr(0, limite - 2) + ' [...]';
            } else if (last == '.' || last == '?' || last == '!') {
                texto = texto.substr(0, limite - 1);
            } else {
                texto = texto.substr(0, limite - 1) + ' [...]';
            }
        }

        alert(texto);
        return (texto);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<h3 id="texto_noticia" class="texto_noticia">
        <%# Eval("Noticia_Conteudo")%>
</h3>
```

A ideia é trazer o conteúdo da notícia que está no banco de dados através do *repeater*, e depois fazer com que o JavaScript pegue o valor e trunque o texto.

Comment: Aí não tem nada de .Net.

Comment: "Esse texto como ficaria depois de truncado, assumindo que o limite seja 15"?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Por exemplo:

"Como truncar texto sem cortar palavras."

com limite de 15 ele ficaria:

"Como truncar texto [...]"

Apesar do limite de texto ser no "t" de "texto", a função iria fazer ele parar apenas depois da palavra.

O problema está sendo para trazer o valor e substituir ele depois.

Comment: Parece simples. Sua rotina deve ler palavra a palavra a medida que soma no total o tamanho dela, quando atingir o limite ou ultrapassar para.

Comment: sim... o código q eu coloquei acima funciona, de certa forma...
Oque está dando problema é que o valor que vai ir para texto não está dando certo...
aquele comando dentro do h3 serve para buscar um valor no banco de dados.
O problema é que não consigo fazer o script pegar esse valor, truncar ele e retornar ele para o mesmo h3

Comment: @Raagatzo, o problema está que o texto já foi jogado pra tela antes que o Javascript pudesse fazer o truncamento. É mais fácil você implementar a resposta em C# do bigown embaixo. Do contrário, vai ter que achar uma forma (nao muito legal) de executar o script _depois_ que o html já recebeu o texto do banco de dados.

Comment: @EricWu sim... concordo contigo... tenho tentado fazer o código dele trazer valores do BD mas ainda estou tendo complicações pra isso... mas se eu conseguir eu aviso vcs :D

Comment: @Raagatzo A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: @bigown o problema ainda não foi resolvido, porque o truncamento eu já havia conseguido fazer em javascript... estou com problema pra trazer os valores do banco de dados, entende?
Mas todos vocês tem me ajudado...

Comment: @Raagatzo você poderia ter resolvido, mas o que você perguntou foi sobre isso. Se o problema era outro, faça outra pergunta definindo claramente o problema. Se você quer que dados devem ser trazidos do banco de dados, você deve perguntar sobre isso, mostrar o que você fez sobre isso e qual a dificuldade. Nessa pergunta você pediu para fazer o truncamento, foi respondido. Cabe a você definir se a resposta é satisfatória para esta pergunta. Não para outras perguntas. Quando fizer uma nova pergunta poderá definir na outra se uma das respostas lá é satisfatória para ela. Eu acho que essa encerrou.

Comment: "A ideia é trazer o conteúdo da notícia que está no banco de dados através do repeater, e depois fazer com que o JavaScript pegue o valor e trunque o texto."

@bigown especifiquei desde o começo como funcionaria

Comment: @bigown felizmente muita gente respondeu aqui, todos procuraram me ajudar, mas nenhuma resposta resolveu meu problema...
Pelo meu código já da pra ver q o javascript trunca o texto, só preciso saber como trazer da tabela do banco para o java script e depois mandar para o h3... 
o Eric Wu soube me explicar o porque minha ideia não estava funcionando, o que me ajudou em partes, mas até agora estou com o problema do inicio

Comment: `Como fazer truncamento de texto sem cortar palavras .Net?` Este é o título. Mais de 90% do texto fala sobre o truncamento. Tem uma frasezinha no final sobre outro assunto, não dá um detalhe sequer sobre ele, nada que permita responder sobre isso. A pergunta não é sobre isso. Faça o que estou lhe falando. Crie uma nova pergunta cujo foco seja o que está querendo saber agora. E coloque detalhes, porque sem eles, será fechada como não clara. Foi respondido o que você perguntou. Novamente, faça o que eu estou te dizendo para obter uma resposta que deseja. Faça outra pergunta.

Comment: Essa não tem mais o que fazer a não ser aceitar o que foi respondido e partir para outra. Não haverá outra resposta sobre outro assunto aqui. O que foi colocado nesta foi respondido. Se não quer aceitar é um direito seu. Estou achando até que é melhor fechar como não clara aqui já que está insistindo que perguntou algo que ninguém está vendo na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

O segredo é usar o [`LastindexOf(' ')`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_Char_) para descobrir onde está o último espaço. Seria algo assim em C#:

```
if (text.Length <= length) {
    return text;
}
if (length <= ellipsis.Length) {
    return ellipsis.Substring(0, length);
}
text = text.Substring(0, length - ellipsis.Length);
var position = text.LastIndexOf(' ');
position = position < 0 ? 0 : position;
return text.Substring(0, position).Trim(new[] { '.', ',', ';', ':', '!', '?' }) + ellipsis;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UQIKZi). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xAL6rh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Ellipsis.cs).

Se quiser fazer em JS é uma conversão simples do algoritmo. O JS possui todos os métodos usados com semântica idêntica.

```js
function trimSpecials(text, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        var isNormal = true;
        for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
            if (text[i] == chars[j]) {
                isNormal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isNormal) result += text[i];
    }
    return result;
}

function ellipsis(text, length, ellipsis) {
    ellipsis = typeof ellipsis !== 'undefined' ? ellipsis : '...';
    if (text.length <= length) return text;
    if (length <= ellipsis.length) return ellipsis.substr(0, length);
    text = text.substr(0, length - ellipsis.length);
    var position = text.lastIndexOf(' ');
    position = position < 0 ? 0 : position;
    return trimSpecials(text.substr(0, position), ['.', ',', ';', ':', '!', '?'])  + ellipsis;
}

var texto = "Este é um teste de texto longo que precisa ser truncado com reticências, sem cortar a palavra.";
for (var i = 0; i < texto.length + 1; ++i) console.log(i + ' : ' + ellipsis(texto, i));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/String/Ellipsis.js).

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer o teste!
Eu estava tentando fazer em javascript mas já havia tentado em .net tbm

Comment: cara... eu consegui fazer o truncamento do texto, mas tem um problema... eu só consigo qndo estabeleço o texto dentro da variável!
Não estou conseguindo trazer o valor da tabela do BD para poder depois truncar ele e jogar no HTML

Comment: Isso é outro problema, deve abrir uma nova pergunta especificamente sobre esse problema. Aproveita e dá uma olhada no [tour]

Comment: mas essa era a pergunta no começo :x
desculpa se não fui claro

Comment: aquele código q postei também dava certo... tentei aproveitar o código em c# q vc postou e tentar fazer ele com um select no banco mas não deu certo

Comment: Precisa de outra pergunta, eu respondi o que foi perguntado aqui, se era outra coisa que queria perguntar tem que ser outra pergunta.

Comment: ta, beleza... tudo bem.. mas não tem como responder aqui mesmo agora que vc entendeu o que preciso?
estou a algum tempo tentando fazer isso pois não tenho experiencia em programação

Comment: @bigown, tentei editar, mas não consegui: Tá `LastInfexOf` no lugar de `LastIndexOf`.

Comment: @EricWu resolvido, obrigado.