# PHP ou JS - Esconder Nome com mais de X careteres

Tags: php, javascript

Usando a frase

```
"OLA SOU FIXE LALALA"
```

como posso apenas mostrar metade, por exemplo

```
"OLA SOU F..."
```

Comment: Aqui tem uma forma mais sofisticada de fazer: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155204/101

Answer (score 2):

PHP:

```
 $string = "OLA SOU FIXE LALALA";
 $metade = strlen($string)/2;
 echo substr($string , 0, $metade).'...';
```

JS:

```
var string = 'OLA SOU FIXE LALALA';
var metade = string.length/2;
alert( string.substring(0, metade) + '...');
```